# Amazon S3: How to use SEO-friendly URLs for Images

Tags: php, image, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, seo

we are using Amazon S3 for displaying images on our website. Right now, the images are saved with the keys:

```
myimages/193-image-small.jpg
myimages/193-image-large.jpg
myimages/194-image-small.jpg
myimages/194-image-large.jpg
```

and so on...

I can embed an image in my page with a code like this:

```
<img src="s3-zone.amazonaws.com/mybucket/myimages/193-image-large.jpg">
```

This is working nice and properly but I want to go a step further and display SEO friendly picture URLs for google like:

```
s3-zone.amazonaws.com/mybucket/myimages/193-super-great-title-for-my-picture.jpg
```

Is that in any way possible to implement and if yes - how?

Comment: are you hoping to have a "transparent url" that is the longer one? Can you simply rename the files?

Comment: I'm contemplating this, and no clever hacks are coming to mind.  I assume the reason you're not storing them in S3 with the names you like, already, is because with the current setup, you don't have to "store" the image name, you can just generate it with string concatenation.  Is that it?  Otherwise it seems like something like myimages/large/193/super-great-title-for-my-picture.jpg would be a suitable key structure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible. Each object in Amazon S3 has one Key Name.

Some options:

- Rename the objects to the name you desire, or
- Point the URLs to your web server, which can translate the URL to the 'normal' URL and retrieve the underlying S3 object -- but this will put load on your web server rather than sending all requests to S3

If you want to be SEO-friendly, it's much better to add an `alt` field to the `img` tag. That counts more than filenames.

For example, see: [How to Optimize Images for Better Search Engine Rankings](http://diythemes.com/thesis/wordpress-seo-image-optimization/)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I expected something like this. I will save my key in the database now and use this to retrieve the right key from the S3.